Pull iTunes 4K/Dolby/HDR metadata and display on my website?
Im trying to create a website that displays the new releases/sales movies from iTunes to my website, I want it to display 4K, Dolby Atmos, HDR tags too, but don't know how to go about it
Also I'd like my code to grab as many titles as possible, at the moment it only displays 15-16 at a time (see below)
Can anyone help?
This is part of my code...
function fetchRecentDiscountedMovies() {
    const url = 'https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=movie&media=movie&limit=200'; 

      const movies = data.results;
      const discountedMovies = movies.filter(movie => movie.trackPrice < 5); // Example threshold for discount

    fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            const movieContainer = document.getElementById('movie-container');
            movieContainer.innerHTML = ''; // Clear previous results


"it only displays 15-16 at a time" - probably due to the filtering on your side? When accessing the API url, it returns way more results. Usually, you should add all filter criteria to the API call, such that limit=200 really leads to 200 results

but I don't understand why only 15-16 results are displayed and not 200?

Where are they displayed? Did you inspect what the API returns?
